# Mounting ftp via curlftpfs on 17.10

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, ftp

On 16.04 i used `curlftpfs#<login>:<pass>@<ip> /media/ftp fuse rw,allow_other,noauto,user 0 0` string inside `/etc/fstab` to mount ftp.

Now on 17.10, when i add this string to fstab, and run `sudo mount -a` nothing happens. But at the same time i can mount it via `curlftpfs <login>:<pass>@<ip> /mnt/ftp` within terminal (already have made my user owner of /mnt/ftp by `chown -R`). Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 8 mount`:

```
Command-line options available for the mount command are:

-a, --all
    Mount  all  filesystems  (of the given types) mentioned in fstab
    (except for those whose line contains the noauto keyword).   The
    filesystems are mounted following their order in fstab.
```

Your `fstab` entry has the `noauto` keyword.

Comment: Oh, I see.. If remove `noauto` from options - able to mount my ftp with `sudo mount -a`. But if i leave /etc/fstab like that and reboot - go to emergency mode instead of login screen.. So there is another question - what option must  i add/remove to automount my ftp folder via fstab record? For now just using .sh added to StartupApplications. And i think  "fstab" approach is "cleaner". But nevertheless, you, @waltinator answered the origin question. So should i just accept your answer, or you can give me advise with fstab - and i can update my question to make more useful for others?

Answer (score 3):

Add the flag: **_netdev** to the string

```
curlftpfs#<login>:<pass>@<ip> /media/ftp fuse _netdev,rw,allow_other,auto,user 0 0
```